# Transmit speaker's voice over bluetooth headset to a camcorder

Tags: microphone, wireless, sound

Do you know about some cheap bluetooth receiver to connect to camcoder's audio input? I want to use bluetooth headset ([BackBeat 903+](http://www.plantronics.com/us/product/backbeat-903-plus)) to transmit speaker's voice to be synchronized with video and recorded by the camcorder (Panasonic HDC-HS300). The camcorder have a JAG mic input.

Comment: You don't say what kind of camera you have, but perhaps something like [this](http://www.amazon.com/Sony-ECMHW2-Wireless-Bluetooth-Microphone/dp/B001PKUUF4/ref=cm_cr_pr_product_top)?

Comment: Before going too far, have you checked what the audio quality is actually like?  Most bluetooth headsets are not known for their outstanding pick up quality, it's just normally not that noticeable over low quality phone audio.